# item ID name or ID inside item in json structure of couchDB, best performance?

Tags: couchdb

The documentation of couchDB seem to only have examples of the format (leaving out parentheses here):

```
[
{id: xyz, content: jfdsh},
{id: abc, content: lkjfd}
...
]
```

I want to use the following format:

```
[
xyz: {content: jfdsh},
abc: {content: lkjfd}
...
]
```

No example in the docs uses this. 1) does this work and 2) is it performant? Firebase seems to opt for the latter for performance. But there are reasons to prefer couchDB...

Grateful for insights!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CouchDB, use documents in json format like this:

```js
{
    "_id": "my_doc", 
    "number": 23
}
```